# Finding value and index of min value in a matrix, grouped by column values

Tags: matlab

I am trying to find the min value **and index** of each group of datapoints in the following matrix using matlab:

```
    a=[0.3 1;
    0.5 1;
    0.2 1;
    0.4 2 ;
    0.43 2;
    0.01 3;
    0.3 3;
    0.23 3];
```

The data is grouped by the value in column 2. i.e. the first three rows are in group 1, the next two rows are in group 2, the last 3 rows are in group 3.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far, I assume you've tried just looping through the matrix and holding the minimum for each group number? Did you have problems applying that? Or are you looking for a better solution?

Comment: yes i tried this solution. The problem i have is with the location/index as the index i get is the location or the order in each group not inside the main matrix.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15588466/what-is-a-fast-way-to-group-values-by-index and many other questions along the same lines...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `accumarray` with `min` to find the minimum values per group:

```
v = accumarray( a(:,2), a(:,1), [], @min )
```

To obtain the indices of the minima, construct the rows:

```
idx = find(ismember(a, [v, unique(a(:, 2))], 'rows'))
```

Also, if you have `m` predetermined groups, you can use `(1:m)'` instead of `unique(...)`.

Comment: I am not famliar with using accumarray, i will try it though thanks. However, Is there another way to do so since the group no. can be up to m values (1, 2, 3, ..., m) .

Comment: @LindaRabady You _really_ should get familiar with `accumarray`, if you want to get better at MATLAB.

Comment: @LindaRabady I've updated Shai's solution to obtain those indices that you're looking for.

Comment: @EitanT Thanks very much for the code, i have tried it and this is exactly what i need. Its definitely quicker than the for loop and gives the index in the main matrix not inside each group.

Comment: @Shai This is a much better solution, I agree

Answer (score 3):

Another option:

```
 min(a(a(:,2)==1))
 min(a(a(:,2)==2)) % etc...
```

should work as long as the numbers in the second column are integers, otherwise the equality test will fail. If using doubles, compare the difference between values to a (very) small tolerance (e.g. 1e-6).

Comment: Thanks very much, this is a better option for me. They are integers

Comment: How do i get the location of each of those min values?

Comment: Call the `min` function with the two output arguments:

`>> [min_val,idx] = min(a(a(:,2)==1))`
`min_val =  0.20000`
`idx =  3`

Comment: @am304 This solution is not efficient at all, as it iterates redundantly over the data multiple times. Also, to fully automate this solution, the unique values should be detected in advance, which adds further unnecessary complexity to the solution.

Comment: Thank you, yes but this will give me the index in the group itself (like in group 1) not in the a matrix. I tried this one already.

Comment: I created a for loop to do so. I have a pre-defined number of groups already.

Comment: @EitanT I tried your suggestion in Octave (don't have MATLAB) and got the following error message:

`>> accumarray( {a(:,2)}, a(:,1), [], @min )`
`error: cellfun: C must be a cell array`
`error: called from:`
`error:   D:\Octave-3.6.2\share\octave\3.6.2\m\general\accumarray.m at line 143, column 13`

Removing the curly braces around `a(:,2)` seems to work (and work well), but does not return the position (index)

Comment: @am304 You don't need the curly braces (take into consideration that there might be compliancy issues between Octave and MATLAB). Also, this is Shai's solution, not mine.

Comment: @EitanT You are right, sorry!!